# Failed to find Evans' further comments on the weak solutions to the Poisson equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with nontrivial boundary and let $W_0^{1,2}(M)$ be the closure of $C_c^\infty(M)$ in the Sobolev space $W^{1,2}(M)$. Suppose $f\in C^\infty(M)$. Given $u\in W_0^{1,2}$ that solves the Poisson equation $\Delta u=f$ **weakly**, I was trying to make $u$ become a strong (classical) solution, and all I have is the PDE book written by Evans. I knew my question is something related to the theory of regularity, and after consulting Evans' book, I was able to presume that $u$ is actually smooth and vanishing on the boundary ($C_0^\infty$), but the question remains: is smoothness enough to guarantee that $u$ solves the Poisson equation in the classical sense?

After going through Evans' book thoroughly, I found nothing more. Or maybe I was foolish enough to not tell the implications. So I came here for a piece of advice. It would be great if someone could indicate precisely where to find relevant discussions in Evans' book. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ill just  do it for the case where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open subset.
You have for any $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(U)$
$$
\int_U \nabla u \cdot \nabla\phi \; \mathrm{d}vol=\int_U f \phi \; \mathrm{d}vol.
$$
Then, you can proceed to integrate by parts (note we can do that, since $u$  is smooth!) to arrive at
$$
\int_U(\Delta u - f)\phi \; \mathrm{d}vol
$$
for any $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(U)$. By the fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations, we have $\Delta u=f$ almost everywhere and by continuity, it holds everywhere.
I should also mention, that in the case of smoothness the weak/distributional gradient and classical gradient agree.
Depending on your definition of the Laplacian, you can adapt this to Riemannian manifold via charts and the definition of Sobolev spaces/Laplacian via charts. Since being a classical solution is a local property, charts will work out just fine.